# Qual a diferença entre "!=" e "<>" em PHP? Qual usar?

Tags: php, operadores

Qual a diferença entre `!=` e `<>`? Qual deles eu devo usar?

Comment: n-e-n-h-u-m-a, é uma *enche-linguiça* do PhP

Comment: @RZ-8121 Não é questão de *enche-linguiça* e sim questão de que na época que o php foi criado (1995) existiam linguagens como VB (classico) que usava `<>` e outras linguagens que usavam `!=` ou seja a ideia era que facilitasse a migração. Realmente as pessoas criticam linguagens a torta e a direita, mas muitas linguagens nasceram em épocas diferentes do pensamento de hoje. Não entenda-me mal, apenas considere como uma critica construtiva. Ou seja é apenas para manter a "portabilidade".

Comment: Dois operadores para uma mesma função é algo confuso. Pode ser útil até para alguns que gostam mais do `<>` do que o `!=`, mas é como o bigown disse, é uma linguagem que o operador de igualdade é o `==`, então o correto seria para o programador usar o `!=` para negar uma igualdade, não faria sentido usar o `<>` sendo que o oposto é o `==`...

Comment: @RZ-8121 não está claro pra você que os operadores fazem a mesma coisa? Onde está a tal da precedência? "Diferente de" é "diferente de" e pronto. Colocar informações que não são verdadeiras numa resposta (sendo que o manual não diz nada ou fala o contrário) é sim um erro.

Comment: @RZ-8121 em linguagens de programação existem as vezes mais de uma maneira de se fazer a mesma coisa e não é uma característica do php apenas. Toda linguagem tem suas peculiaridades.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Segundo a documentação do PHP ambos são operadores de comparação e servem para comparar se um valor é diferente de outro.

Exemplo (usando a função `var_dump()` para retornar o resultado):

```
<?php
   var_dump( 7 != 7 ); // FALSE, pois não são diferentes

   var_dump( 7 != 6 ); // TRUE, pois são diferentes

   var_dump( 7 <> 7 ); // FALSE, pois não são diferentes

   var_dump( 7 <> 6 ); // TRUE, pois são diferentes
?>
```

O uso varia conforme a sua preferência, mas o mais comum é utilizar `!=`.

Você pode ver mais a respeito **[diretamente na documentação do PHP aqui](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.operators.comparison.php)** e sobre a precedência [**aqui.**](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.operators.precedence.php)

Answer (score 8):

Nenhuma, são sinônimos exatos. São só formas diferentes de escrever. Escolha qual achar mais confortável. Eu vejo que é mais comum usar o `!=` para ficar simétrico com o `==` ("igual"), já que `!=` seria o mesmo que dizer "não igual".

[Documentação](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Conceptual.md).